# AngularJS, better way to subtotalize items from ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm doing a table and totalizing all the items, but now I'm trying to get the value from some line only, I'm from Jquery and I'm thinking like Jquery apps, there a good way to do this in AngularJS?

I put a IMG to explain the situation.

Some advice?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I get a good solution, just create and change a new atributte and to call a method that will calculate all value selected.

Enjoy!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular.Foreach to loop over the selected items and calculate the subtotal.

```
$scope.subtotal = function() {
        var total = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
            total += item.cost;
        })
        return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that initially your table will have all the checkbox controls unchecked then you can use `ng-change` directive and call below function:

```
$scope.changeTotal = function (item) {
  if (item.selected) {
    $scope.total += item.price;
  } else {
    $scope.total -= item.price;
  }    
}
```

Here is an example: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bwhhDS1OMZopdSYh51tC?p=preview)